# conflicting requests and missing packages while installing KDE Plasma Workspaces

Tags: rhel, kde-plasma, centos8

I am completely new to RHEL based OSes. Trying to switch from GNOME to KDE.
Followed the instructions at this [link](https://linuxconfig.org/installation-of-kde-desktop-environment-on-centos-7#:%7E:text=Installing%20KDE%20desktop%20environment%20is,and%20enable%20the%20EPEL%20repository.&text=Next%2C%20type%20the%20following%20dnf,and%20base-x%20group%20packages.)

Got some errors except for step 1. Adding some screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also this problem is occuring after I installed a product called EDB. (https://www.enterprisedb.com/)

Comment: It would help if you could a) quote the instructions in step 1 instead of just dropping a link, b) crop your images a bit, and c) include them directly instead of inside a code block to make the instantly visible (or at least make the links clickable).

Comment: Christian I have given links to images as per your advise. Could'nt figure out how to display images directly. Newbee to SO as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Hakob! I recommend you to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and ease to other users to help you!